# How do you use a variable as an index when slicing strings in Python?

Tags: python, string, slice

I've been trying to slice two characters out of a string using a loop, but instead of grabbing two characters, it only grabs one.

I've tried:

```
input[i:i+1]
```

and

```
input[i:(i+1)]
```

but neither seems to work.

How do I use a variable for slicing?

The full routine:

```
def StringTo2ByteList(input):
    # converts data string to a byte list, written for ascii input only
    rlist = []
    for i in range(0, len(input), 2):
        rlist.append(input[i:(i+1)])
    return rlist
```

Comment: note: `input` as a variable name shadows a built-in function

Comment: @wim On Python 2, it shadows a built-in function _you should almost never be using anyway_. I'd put it in a category with `id` and `file` (which are often shadowed even in the standard library) rather than `list` or `dict` etc.

Comment: [nice picture that explains how to slice a string in Python](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch03.html#fig-string-slicing)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The slice values aren't the start and end *characters* of the slice, they're the start and end **points**. If you want to slice two elements then your stop must be **2** greater than your start.

```
input[i:i+2]
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked great.  It's sure counter-intuitive, will have to wrap my head around it.

Comment: @eryksun, the only not-so-intuitive aspect of range was that it won't max out at the `stop` but at the highest value less than stop.  I finally found the part in the Python tutorial that diagrammed what they're doing with the slicing indices, so I'm good now.

Comment: Sometimes it's better to think of it as `[start:start+size]` rather than `[start:stop]`.

Comment: @Ignacio It's half true and your answer puts the two halves in the brains. See my answer.

Answer (score 6):

A nice way to remember slice indexing is to think of the numbers as labeling the positions between the elements.

[image: slice example]

So for example to slice `ba` you would use `fruit[0:2]`.  When thinking of it this way, things no longer seem counter-intuitive, and you can easily avoid making off-by-one errors in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Reasoning on the basis of the in-between positions works when we do a left-to-right iteration:

```
li = [10, 20, 55, 65, 75, 120, 1000]
print 'forward slicing li[2:5]    ->',li[2:5]
# prints forward slicing li[2:5]    -> [55, 65, 75]
```

because pos 2 is between 20 / 55 and pos 5 is between 75 / 120

.

But it doesn't work when we do right-to-left iteration:

```
li = [10, 20, 55, 65, 75, 120, 1000]
print li
print 'reverse slicing li[5:2:-1] ->',li[5:2:-1]
# prints reverse slicing li[5:2:-1] -> [120, 75, 65]
```

**We must think of li[ 5 : 2 : -1 ] as :

from element li[5]** (which is 120) **as far as uncomprised element li[2]** (which is 55)
 that is to say
**from element li[5]** (which is 120)  **only as far as li[3] included** (which is 65) .

.

That makes dangerous reverse slicing from the very end:

```
li = [10, 20, 55, 65, 75, 120, 1000]
print li[ -1 : 2  : -1 ]
# prints [1000, 120, 75, 65] not [120, 75, 65, 55]
# the same as:
print li[  None : 2 : -1 ]
# prints [1000, 120, 75, 65]
print li[       : 2 : -1 ]
# prints [1000, 120, 75, 65]
```

and

```
li = [10, 20, 55, 65, 75, 120, 1000]
print li[ 4 : 0 : -1]
# prints [75, 65, 55, 20] , not [65, 55, 20, 10]
```

.

In case of difficulty to think like that, a manner to prevent errors is to write

```
print list(reversed(li[2:5]))
# prints [75, 65, 55]
print list(reversed(li[2:-1]))
# prints [120, 75, 65, 55]
print list(reversed(li[0:4]))
# prints [65, 55, 20, 10]
```

.

Note that the only way to obtain a reverse slicing as far as the first element INCLUDED is

```
print li[ 4 :      : -1]
```

that stands for

```
print li[ 4 : None : -1]
```