# get substring from string based on start and end position python

Tags: python, string

How do I get substring from string based on start and end position and do it for each row in a table. the start and end positions are found in the same table at the same row as an initial string but in a different columns.
Input:

```
String                      Start End
1. Kids walking to school   0     3
2. Hello world              2     4
3. Today is a great day     6     9
```

Desired output:

```
String                      Start End Substring
1. Kids walking to school   0     3   Kids
2. Hello world              2     4   llo
3. Today is a great day     6     9   is a
```

Comment: Take a read through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/289/indexing-and-slicing#t=201611011650314405243)

Comment: Provide more details about your question with example inputs and expected outputs. Also include what you have tried and what did not work.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with "table"?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to do it

Comment: Have you already created the first table of inputs? There's many different ways to do this from scratch..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use a variable as an index when slicing strings in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625326/how-do-you-use-a-variable-as-an-index-when-slicing-strings-in-python)

Comment: What is the format of your input data?

Comment: Is your table a list of strings? In a text file? Some form of dataframe? A table in a database?

Comment: My input is a list of strings and I read it in dataframe

Answer (score 1):

You can use string slicing, just like you would do for a list, or any other sequence. For the string `string = 'Kids walking to school'`, `string[0:4]` will return 'Kids'. Note that the slicing starts at index 0 and stops at index 3 (4 - 1).

The following code snippet will give you a hint on how to proceed.

```
table = [
('Kids walking to school', 0, 3),
('Hello world', 2, 4),
('Today is a great day', 6, 9)
]

substring = []

for line in table:
    substrig.append(line[0][line[1]:line[2] + 1])
```

As you didn't mentioned what kind of data structure is you table and how you get it, I abstracted it with a list of tuples like (string, start, stop). The idea is that for each line in table, you'll get the substring string[start:stop + 1].

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Just one question why do I need +1?

Comment: You need the +1 once the string slicing is inclusive for the start, but exclusive for the stop. This means that string[start:stop] will get elements starting from start (start inclusive) and stopping at one element before the stop (exclusive).

Comment: If it worked, could you please mark my answer as the solution, please? It will help other people to find the solution easier. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
table = [
['Kids walking to school', 0, 3],
['Hello world', 2, 4],
['Today is a great day', 6, 9]
]

substring = []

for line in table:
    size = line[0].find(' ')
    substring = line[0]
    line.append(substring[0:size])

print(table)
```

Please use list rather using tuples datatype to hold the table values, because tuple in python are immutable datatype. To update the table entries as per your need, you can use the above code snippet.

Comment: Please use list rather using tuples datatype to hold the table values, because tuple in python are immutable datatype. To update the table entries as per your need, you can use the above code snippet. Please review and share your comments @ 9597327310.
    
        **Output:**
        [['Kids walking to school', 0, 3, 'Kids'], 
        ['Hello world', 2, 4, 'Hello'],
        ['Today is a great day', 6, 9, 'Today']]

Comment: Hello Guhan!  Could you edit your question to incorporate the text within your comment?  In addition, please read the [tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).